# check and uncheck check in click of li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to check and unchecked a checkbox in JavaScript when click whole `li`. I want the checkbox checked if checked and click then unchecked.

```js
function handleClick(cb) {
      if(jQuery('related-products-field')){

      document.getElementById('related-checkbox-'+cb).checked = true;
  numArray.push(cb);
      //alert(numArray);
        //var allele = document.getElementById("dialog").innerHTML = numArray;
        document.getElementById('related-products-field').value = numArray.join(",");
     } 

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="item odd" onclick="handleClick(338);" id="">
    <span class="input-holder"><input type="checkbox" id="related-checkbox-338" class="checkbox related-checkbox" name="related_products[]" value="338">ADD</span>
    <div class="product" id="disbaledtoclick">
       <a disabled="" href="" title="" class="product-image"><img src="https://www.example.com/image.jpg" width="100px" height="100"></a>
       <div class="product-details">
          <p class="product-name"><a href="" disabled=""> Small Teddy Bear (6")</a></p>
          <div class="price-box">
          <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-2-related">
          <span class="price" disabled="">279.0000</span></span>
       </div>

     </div>

 </div></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch the checked state of the checkbox, you can assign the opposite value to it.

```js
function changeCheckbox(){

  let cbox = document.getElementById('cBox');
  cbox.checked = !(cbox.checked);

}
```

```html
<label>checkbox <input type="checkbox" id="cBox" /></label>
<button onclick="changeCheckbox();">Change Checkbox</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using jQuery you can do the following:

```
 function handleClick(cb) {
      if(jQuery('related-products-field')){
        // since you are using this checkbox twice in the function, it's a good idea to define it as a variable.
        var checkbox = jQuery('#related-checkbox-'+cb);
        // The is(':checked') function checks if the checkbox is checked
        var isChecked = checkbox.is(':checked');
        // We then assign the opposite of the current state to the 'checked' attribute.
        checkbox.prop('checked', !isChecked);

        // do the rest of the function
     } 

}
```

Comment: I can click on checkbox or other place in li

Comment: So what is the issue? Did you test the code I provided? Does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery code which makes the job in one line :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('li.item.odd').on('click', function(){
            $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", !$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked"));
        });
    });
```

copy / paste this full code to see the result :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="item odd">
    <span class="input-holder"><input type="checkbox" id="related-checkbox-338" class="checkbox related-checkbox" name="related_products[]" value="338">ADD</span>
    <div class="product" id="disbaledtoclick">
       <a disabled="" href="" title="" class="product-image"><img src="https://www.example.com/image.jpg" width="100px" height="100"></a>
       <div class="product-details">
          <p class="product-name"><a href="" disabled=""> Small Teddy Bear (6")</a></p>
          <div class="price-box">
          <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-2-related">
          <span class="price" disabled="">279.0000</span></span>
       </div>

     </div>

 </div></li>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('li.item.odd').on('click', function(){
            $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", !$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked"));
        });
    });
 </script>
```